# Cannot click element in selenium - But both css & xpath are validate paths

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I cannot click this element, tried CSS selector and Xpaths. Can anyone help, keep getting invalid selector, XPath/cannot locate element. Yet when I use the inspector to validate these elements they are correct, why can't my web driver script locate them?

HTML:

```
<div class="ap-ba-well-button"> 
    <!-- ngIf: service.booking_status_type !== 'Not Bookable Online' -->
    <button ng-if="service.booking_status_type !== 'Not Bookable Online'" class="ap-button ng-binding ng-scope">Book</button>
    <!-- end ngIf: service.booking_status_type !== 'Not Bookable Online' --> 
    <!-- ngIf: service.booking_status_type === 'Not Bookable Online' --> 
</div>
```

Code trials:

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ap-popover-well-group-single:nth-child(1) .ap-button").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(“//?/button[@innertext='Book']”) 
driver.find_element_by_xpath(“/html//span[@class='ng-scope']/ap-booking-app[@class='ng-scope']/div[@class='ap-ba-wrapper ng-scope']/div[@class='ap-ba-container with-footer']//ap-booking-app-step-services[@data='data']/div/div[1]//div[@class='ap-ba-well-single ng-scope']//button[@class='ap-button ng-binding ng-scope']”)
```

any help will be great

Comment: Please post your HTML as well?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the desired element is not present inside the webpage when you want to make a click, even if you have provided a correct path.

My way of going around this problem is like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as E

clickButton = WebDriverWait(browser,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "ID")))
```

Comment: seems common response by all, but this still isnt working.Going to try a robotframework

Comment: Well, I have faced this problem many times, and every time I used something new to overcome it, so do I bit research try out many implementations and find the best that suits your problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the HTML you have provided and your code trials it is pretty much evident that the element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element, so you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.ap-ba-well-button button.ap-button.ng-binding.ng-scope"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='ap-ba-well-button']//button[@class='ap-button ng-binding ng-scope' and text()='Book']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: still having issues the same issues with this code, yes this is angular, should i be looking at a different approach here?

Comment: @3eternus Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Answer (score 0):

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and `element_to_be_clickable`() and following Xpath Options.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[text()='Book']"))).click()
```

OR

```
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@class='ap-button ng-binding ng-scope' and text()='Book']"))).click()
```

You need to import following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: stil not workingthink this is an angular related problem im trying a robot framework

Comment: @3eternus : Share your url If possible.I believe the `book` button must be inside an `iframe`? Check your DOM if you find any `iframe` above `book` button?